# Unable to mimmick POSTMAN request in Volley

Tags: java, android, json, httprequest, android-volley

I am new to using Volley on Android. Using the old http client stuff I could make my web requests perfectly with the various headers and parameters, now I am unable. My request looks like this in Postman:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Host: my.api.co.za
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

username=test&password=1234&grant_type=password
```

Yet I am unable to recreate and execute this request in Volley. I have tried making a custom Json request class that extends `Request<JSONObject>` but to no avail. Please see my code below:

```
public class CustomJsonRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener;
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public CustomJsonRequest(int method, String url, Listener<JSONObject> responseListener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.listener = responseListener;
    }

    @Override
    public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map headers = new HashMap();
        headers.put("Accept", "application/json");
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("username", "test");
        params.put("password", "1234");
        params.put("grant_type", "password");
        if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
            return encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Converts <code>params</code> into an application/x-www-form-urlencoded encoded string.
     */
    private byte[] encodeParameters(Map<String, String> params, String paramsEncoding) {
        StringBuilder encodedParams = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), paramsEncoding));
                encodedParams.append('=');
                encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), paramsEncoding));
                encodedParams.append('&');
            }
            encodedParams.deleteCharAt(encodedParams.lastIndexOf("&"));
            Log.e("params", encodedParams.toString());
            return encodedParams.toString().getBytes(paramsEncoding);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding, uee);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            Log.e("response", response.toString());
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e("response", response.toString());
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    private Priority mPriority;

    public void setPriority(Priority priority) {
        mPriority = priority;
    }

    @Override
    public Priority getPriority() {
        return mPriority == null ? Priority.NORMAL : mPriority;
    }
}
```

And I call this as follows in my `MainActivity` class:

```
CustomJsonRequest request = new CustomJsonRequest(Request.Method.POST, AUTH_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                //showJSON(response);
                VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                txtError(error);
            }
        });
```

Can somebody tell me where I am going wrong in creating this request?

Comment: I don't know Volley but here is my guess : you expect a JSONObject but send parameters in the URL. You should probably send the parameters as a JSON object in the request body.

Comment: For clarification, that request in Postman works perfectly with a 200 response code. I don't want to be sending parameters in the URL, unless that is in fact what I'm doing in Postman?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with my following sample code:

```
    String url = "http://server/token";
    Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();
    stringMap.put("grant_type", "password");
    stringMap.put("username", "bnk");
    stringMap.put("password", "bnk123");
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    Iterator entries = stringMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
        builder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey().toString(), entry.getValue().toString());
        entries.remove();
    }
    String requestBody = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, requestBody, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // do something...
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // do something...
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        }
    };
```

---

***UPDATE:***

If your project uses Google's official volley as a module, you should add the following into `JsonObjectRequest.java` file:

```
    public JsonObjectRequest(int method, String url, String requestBody,
                             Listener<JSONObject> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(method, url, requestBody, listener, errorListener);
    }
```

---

***UPDATE 2:***

If you don't want to edit `JsonObjectRequest.java` file as I mentioned above, you can use the following code:

```
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                // do something...
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // do something...
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            }

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                // init parameters
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("grant_type", "password");
                params.put("username", "bnk");
                params.put("password", "bnk123");
                // encode parameters (can use Uri.Builder as above)
                String paramsEncoding = "UTF-8";
                StringBuilder encodedParams = new StringBuilder();
                try {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                        encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), paramsEncoding));
                        encodedParams.append('=');
                        encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), paramsEncoding));
                        encodedParams.append('&');
                    }
                    return encodedParams.toString().getBytes(paramsEncoding);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding, uee);
                }
            }
        };
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This code doesn't compile for me, as you cannot pass requestBody as a parameter of JsonObjectRequest, this parameter needs to be of type JsonObject.

Comment: How did you use Volley lib in your project? If it is Google's official volley, did you use it as a module or JAR file?